# R ggbiplot aesthetics

Tags: r, ggbiplot

is it possible to change the thickness of the ellipses (incl circle) in ggbiplot? The arguments don't seem to have that option. Is there another way around it? So far I've dealt with this issue by making my data points more transparent.

Comment: Which package is this function from?

Comment: ggbiplot is a package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed you got a recent version of `ggbiplot` from github (19 Jun 2015 https://github.com/vqv/ggbiplot). In this one, the circle thickness is hard-coded, but you can modify the code easily. The parameter in question is set here (around line 86 in the definition of `ggbiplot()`):

```
if (circle) {
      theta <- c(seq(-pi, pi, length = 50), seq(pi, -pi, 
                                                length = 50))
      circle <- data.frame(xvar = r * cos(theta), yvar = r * 
                             sin(theta))
      g <- g + geom_path(data = circle, color = muted("white"), 
                         size = 1/2, # <= MODIFY HERE
      alpha = 1/3)
        }
```

Comment: thanks. i tried edit(ggbiplot) and changed the 'size' at line 87 plus hit save but it won't take. My guess is that I don't have rights to the folder (corporate machine). So I'd probably have to move the library and relink via .libPath()...argghhh

Comment: just type `ggbiplot` to get the function definition, copy it to your editor, make the modification, and define a new `ggbiplot` function.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the `ggbiplot` code into a  new function and changing it works, but the change in line 87 only works if `var.axes = TRUE`, which is the default. If you set `var.axes = FALSE` then you need to add a `size` parameter to the call in line 124. Something like `g <- g + geom_path(data = ell, aes(color = groups, group = groups),size=2)`.